# Generating csv file from mongodb using node.js csv module

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv

I need finer control on how data is output to csv so I cannot use mongoexport. I would like to read in one mongodb document at a time and write to csv formatted line in a file. If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be helpful. If all I need to consider in writing csv values is escaping double quotes I can probably just write out the line without the need of csv module. Mainly concerned about the csv creation part.

Answer (score 3):

You can use some javascript ( with or without loading any external javascript library).

eg. myCsvWriter.js

```
db.myCollectionName.find(SOME_CONDITIONS).forEach(
   function(doc)
   {
      docId = doc._id;
      docName = doc.name;
      print('"" + docId + '","' + docName + '"');
   }

);
```

Command to run :

```
mongo --quiet myDatabaseName myCsvWriter.js  >  /tmp/myOutput.csv
```

You will have to write custom Javascript to properly create the CSV string by escaping the seperator and quoting the values, or you can also load some javascript csv library in mongo shell and use that.

Comment: Thank you. Can start with that. This CSV must be importable into mysql. I can slash escape double quotes and commas and write with fs